# How can you make canvas shapes move faster without them desyncing?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So, i've coded this canvas animation and I would like the shape to move faster though when doing so the shapes desync.

When I increment the values show below, so that the shapes would faster, they do so but eventually move away from eachother and desync.

```
    if (this.dir[i][j] === 'downright') { //go down and right
      this.boxLines[i][j].y += 1;
      this.boxLines[i][j].x += 1;
    }
    if (this.dir[i][j] === 'downleft') { //go down and left
      this.boxLines[i][j].y += 1;
      this.boxLines[i][j].x -= 1;
    }
    if (this.dir[i][j] === 'upright') { //go up and right
      this.boxLines[i][j].y -= 1;
      this.boxLines[i][j].x += 1;
    }
    if (this.dir[i][j] === 'upleft') { //go up and left
      this.boxLines[i][j].y -= 1;
      this.boxLines[i][j].x -= 1;
    }
```

Any way to fix that or could i go about it some other way?

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frankpettersson/nqmy3fkd/7/

Comment: Just tried your fiddle. When I replace all the `+= 1` and `-= 1` parts with `+= 2` and `-= 2` everything works fine. **EDIT** OK, you have to wait for quite some time for the effect to appear.

Comment: I watched the problem happen. It happens when it hits a corner, I suspect because you haven't accounted for the edge case where a block hits the corner of the screen.

Comment: @aptriangle yeah, there's definitely something wonky with the edge detection and especially corner detection